# Rcpp and "optional" arguments on functions

Tags: rcpp

I need a Rcpp function to behave depending in the type of input. Suppose you want to double every element of a matrix, but if you have no matrix, you return a matrix filled with "2" of a specific dimension. In R it'd be something like:

```
twoMatrix = function(oldMatrix = NULL, dim=c(10,10)){
 if(!is.null(oldMatrix)){return(2*oldMatrix)}
 return(matrix(2,nrow=dim[1],ncol=dim[2]))
}
```

But when I try to write the Rcpp function, I'm having trouble on how to define the default values and checking wheter the user has selected one type or another.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix twoMatrixRcpp(NumericMatrix OldMatrix, IntegerVector dim){
 ...
}
```

How do I set default arguments so that it works like R's NULL value in the sense that I can check wheter the user has specified it's value or not? And how to check it inside the function?

Comment: I think you may want to look at `Rcpp::Nullable<>`.